# Why are some applications on the Market not on AppBrain as well?

Tags: google-play-store, app-brain

Take [this game](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobjoy.roadwarrior); why is present on the Android Market but not on AppBrain?

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps a question better asked of AppBrain themselves?  Another game by same developer is on AppBrain: http://www.appbrain.com/browse/dev/Top+Free+Apps+and+Games

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason can be find in AppBrain [FAQ](http://www.appbrain.com/info/faq):

> **4.I cannot find some apps, what's going on?**
>   It always says "The requested item could not be found". AppBrain lists applications that
>   are available in the US that are available for Android version 1.6 and
>   up for devices with a normal screen size. Developers can restrict
>   availability of apps by country, Android version and screen size. This
>   means that if you're not in the USA, have a device with a small screen
>   size (for instance the HTC Wildfire or Tattoo), or when you're not on
>   the latest version of Android, you may often get the "not found"
>   message from the Android market.

So, to give you an example, I am a developer and published an app on Android Market, that is restricted to France and Germany, so users from those country will find it on Android Market, but not on AppBrain, who lists only US applications.

Comment: This is not what @michelemarcon is asking.  AppBrain's FAQ entry you quoted is talking about the case where you see an app on AppBrain, but Android Market gives a "could not be found" error.  In this case the opposite is happening.  You CAN find the app on Android Market, but it's missing from AppBrain.

Comment: The faq entry clearly explains situations where the game is available on the market but not on appbrain and that is what the OP is asking

Comment: @Chahk Please read it more carefully; it's exactly THAT case that is referred in the AppBrain FAQ.

Comment: I don't see how `you may often get the "not found" message from the Android market` can be interpreted as apps missing on AppBrain.

Comment: @Chahk Well, I agree that last row it's not perfect wording, though the rest of the answer is quite clear that it's talking about apps missing on AppBrain(it's their FAQ, anyway, not Android Market's). And even for `the "not found" message from the Android market`, AppBrain it's the one receiving it for you, when it's searching for that app in a filtred selection(country=US)of Android Market apps list.

Comment: @Adinia: I'm still not convinced, so I reached out to AppBrain for clarification :) As a note, the app in question IS available in the US, while another one from the same developer is not, and also can't be found on AppBrain. However, the interesting parts about "Road Warrior" game are its listed OS and Size requirements: "Varies with device".  Could be the reason AppBrain cannot display it.

Comment: @Chahk Well, then please keep us posted if you receive any reply from AppBrain. :)